# Why in potentiometer we says that potential gets decreased?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

[image]

**here potential is said to decrease from a to b ,why it is so and  why there is potential drop from a to b please explain?**

Comment: Note that in the circuit drawn, there is a [rheostat](https://eepower.com/resistor-guide/resistor-types/rheostat/#) (two-terminal adjustable resistor) present rather than a potentiometer (three-terminal adjustable voltage divider). One can wire a potentiometer for use as a rheostat.

Answer (score 1):

Positive charge flowing from A to B does work against resistive forces (due to collisions with ions forming the structure of the wire). It therefore gradually loses the ability to do work that it possessed when it was at A. In other words it loses electrical potential energy – the ability to do work because of its position (in an electric field set up by the battery).

We say that there is a drop in potential from A to B, meaning a drop in electrical potential energy per unit charge that we can imagine going from A to B.